# Count days in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to count X days starting on some specific day, but I don't know how to sum these days accosrding to the number of days on each month (e.g. February having 28 or 29, March 31 but April 30...).

I know there is the function `daysact( startDate, endDate )`, but this way I have to try dates until I reach the result I want, and what I need is for the program to count X days from the `startDate` and return the `endDate`. For example, if I want to count 90 days from tomorrow, I have done:

```
startDate = '8-jan-2016';
endDate = '7-apr-2016';
numDays = daysact( startDate, endDate );
```

but I have had to try dates until the function returned exactly 90 (I know it's fairly simple, but the final program will have to do this for different values of days and different starting dates...)

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

```
startDate = '8-jan-2016';
NumDays = 90;
tmp = datevec(startDate);
tmp(3)=tmp(3)+90;
endDate = datestr(tmp)
```

This uses [`datevec`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) to transform your string into a vector of `[Y M D HH MM SS]`, so by adding the desired number of days, 90, to the third element you add 90 days to the start date. Then transform the vector back using [`datestr`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html), which makes it a recognisable date again.

As per [@excaza's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680247/count-days-in-matlab#comment57106562_34680488) [`datenum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) does approximately the same thing, returning the number of days since `0 January 0000`, so the same could be accomplished using:

```
startDate = '8-jan-2016';
NumDays = 90;
endDate = datestr(datenum(startDate)+NumDays);
```

which is a bit more concise, at the cost of having to convert everything to fractions of days.

One-lining it because why not:

```
endDate = datestr(datenum('8-jan-2016')+90);
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the serial date returned by [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) is `days since January 0, 0000` so you can just add or diff that.

Answer (score 3):

2014b and later:

```
datetime(2016,1,8) + days(90)
datetime(2016,1,8) + 90

datetime('today') + days(90)
datetime('today') + 90

datetime('tomorrow') + days(90)
datetime('tomorrow') + 90
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as an alternative.  It was mentioned by @excaza in a comment to @Adriaan's answer.

```
myDate = datenum(2016,1,8); % datenumber for january 8 2016
newDate = myDate + 90; % add 90 days
newDate2 = myDate + 2/24; % add 2 hours
newDate3 = myDate + 93/1440; % add 93 minutes
```

Then you can print the dates with `datestr`.

```
datestr(newDate)

ans =

07-Apr-2016

>> datestr(newDate2)

ans =

08-Jan-2016 02:00:00

>> datestr(newDate3)

ans =

08-Jan-2016 01:33:00
```

`datenum` can take many inputs and even user defined formats to read the date strings.